# Modify and add html from asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to add several `<img>` tags to my html document from `asp.net` codebehind. I looked at [Adding Html from Code Behind in Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854437/adding-html-from-code-behind-in-asp-net) and it seems to be the solution, but I'm not sure how `divcontrol.Controls.Add` determines where exactly it's going to start adding html. For all I know, it's at the end of the html. I also found [Write Html Markup from code behind in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536369/write-html-markup-from-code-behind-in-asp-net), but I'm not certain how to use it either.

So here's the `html` that I'm using. How can I add the `img` tag I have also included?:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Gallery</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/jquery-11.0.min.js'></script>  
    <script type='text/javascript' src='theme-tiles.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <h2>Tiles - Justified</h2>
    <div id="gallery" style="display:none;">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            jQuery("#gallery").gallery({
                tiles_type: "justified"
            });

        });

    </script>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the `<img>` tag that I need to add between the `<div id="gallery">` tag:

```
<img alt="img1"
    src="images/thumbs/tile1.jpg"
    data-image="images/big/tile1.jpg"
    style="display:none"/>
</a>
```

This is the code I would use to add the `html`:

```
HtmlGenericControl divcontrol = new HtmlGenericControl();
divcontrol.Attributes["class"] = "sxro sx1co";
divcontrol.TagName = "div";
pnlUserSearch.Controls.Add(divcontrol);
Label question = new Label();
divcontrol.Controls.Add(question); // add to the new div, not to the panel
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating client-side HTML (not server controls) then you can just create a `Literal`, like this:

```
<div id="gallery" style="display:none;">    
  <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="MyLiteral" />
</div>
```

Then, in your code-behind, set

```
MyLiteral.Text = "<whatever html you want>"
```

I'm answering your question literally (no pun intended.) There may be better/other ways to accomplish the end goal. Mixing "normal" client HTML with webforms can get a little messy. Webforms wants you to do everything its way.

It might make more sense if your container div (`gallery`) is a server control instead. If you're looking to add multiple images then perhaps what you need is a `Repeater`.

To be really honest, if you're not too far down the development path it might be best to take a look at ASP.NET MVC instead.

---

Another approach:

Just add your image itself as a server control directly in the markup.

```
<div id="gallery" style="display:none;">    
  <img runat="server" ID="MyImage" Visible="False"/>
</div>
```

In your code-behind if you want to display it,

```
MyImage.Src = "/image url";
MyImage.Visible = true;
```